# Angular 5 with ngx-cookie and systemjs.config.js

Tags: angular, cookies, angular5

I'm migrating a project from AngularJS 1 to Angular 5. I need a package for cookie manipulation, so I used [ngx-cookie](https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie) . But I cannot change systemjs.config.js as the instructions say, simply becuase the systemjs.config.js was deprecated :) Is there an way to use old packages as such or should I look for another one availble through cli ?

Comment: I suggest you try [ngx-cookie-service](https://github.com/7leads/ngx-cookie-service)

Answer (score 2):

Run following command on root directory of your project:

```
npm install ngx-cookie-service --save
```

In your app.module.ts import ngx-cookie-service and inject in providers array like this:

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  providers: [ CookieService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now you just need to use CookieService where you want (Component or service) like this:

```
constructor( private cookieService: CookieService ) { }

  // code to set cookie
    this.cookieService.set( 'cookieName', 'cookieValue' );
  // code to get cookie
    this.cookieValue = this.cookieService.get('cookieName');
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: so I guess, I was confused by package evolution :) ngx-cookie-service works fine, thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you add a code example of a  simple call to expire cookie named 'myCookie' ?, and one to delete same cookie.  Every variation I try does not seem to work for expiring or deleting the cookie, I can't find an actual real world example anywhere.

Comment: this.cookieservice.deleteAll(); also does nothing ??? So far I can get the value and check the value but thats it.